# Expected MyPy errors when using Generic class but none given

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I run mypy on the following program but I get no error. It says: *"Success: no issues found in 1 source file"*

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class MyClass(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value: T) -> None:
        self.value: T = value

    def get_val(self) -> T:
        return self.value

    def set_val(self, target_value: T) -> None:
        self.value = target_value


class MyClassInt(MyClass[int]):
    pass

def main():
    my_var = MyClassInt(value='six')
    my_var.set_val("str")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I would expect two errors. One when I call the `MyClassInt` constructor and one at `my_var.set_val("str")`.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

For what it's worth, PyCharm (2021.2.2) does give two warnings.

[image]

Comment: Your `main` function is untyped which apparently makes mypy ignore untyped calls in it.  Putting `-> None` after `main` make mypy complain as expected.  I always turn the `--strict`  flag of mypy on to make mypy spot these untyped functions and some other stuff.

Comment: Thanks @qouify. If you add this as an answer I will accept it.